# Live video streaming using progressive download (and not RTMP) in Flash

Tags: flash, video, streaming, flash-media-server

Is it possible to use progressive download for near real-time playback of a live video stream recorded with a webcam?

What I need is that a video stream is recorded on one end, uploaded in real-time to a server and downloaded with a short delay, but in real-time, using progressive download (i.e., HTTP streaming) on another end for playback.

Is it possible or does it require the use of RTMP? If it's possible, then does it require that Flash Media Server runs on a server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

What you are describing above basically is live streaming, and there is no real way around that.

- capture
- push to server
- buffer
- push/pull to/from client with slight delay

The standard approach for doing live streaming on the Intertubes is to use a server like FMS.  There are others you may want to consider:

- **[Wowza](http://www.wowzamedia.com)** (fairly inexpensive, Java-based)
- **[Red5](http://red5.org)** (open source, arguably 'immature', Java-based)

All that said, it looks like Apple is going to put [live streaming via HTTP capabilities into the iPhone](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/apple_submits_new_spec_for_live_streaming_to_ietf.php) as they have made a [IETF standard submission](http://www.ietf.org/internet-drafts/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-00.txt).  My bet is that this will become an industry standard as everyone is all gaga about the iPhone.

If you don't have the time, skills or resources, then FMS/Wowza/Red5 is the way to go.  If you want to get neck-deep in streaming for year on end then almost anything is possible

Answer (score 1):

Adobe just announced support for HTTP Streaming (live and VOD) in Flash Player 10.1. This functionality is still in beta, however.

Also, Akamai is implementing this support with Flash using their hosting, and this should be ready first. http://www.contentinople.com/author.asp?section_id=450&doc_id=182447